# How to to check if Coil ImageRequest is complete before returning the bitmap value

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, coil

I'm trying to return the bitmap value from a lambda function but I get the error: `lateinit property bitmap has not been initialized` ... Is there a way to check if the ImageRequest is complete before returning the bitmap?

```
fun getBitmap(context:Context,imageUrl: String) : Bitmap{

    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .target { drawable ->
           bitmap  = drawable.toBitmap() // This is the bitmap 
        }
        .build()
    ImageLoader(context).enqueue(imageRequest)

    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... I don't have much time to explain. Just see the code and understand.

You have to use **execute()** instead of **enqueue()**. See

```
 private suspend fun getBitmap(context: Context, url: String): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(url)
            .target(
                onStart = {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Coil loader started.")
                },
                onSuccess = { result ->
                    Log.e(TAG, "Coil loader success.")
                    bitmap = result.toBitmapOrNull() // Or (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                },
                onError = {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Coil loading error")
                }
            )
            .build()
        context.imageLoader.execute(request)

        return bitmap
    }
```

Comment: When I pass getBitmap as a parameter i get the error "Suspend function 'getBitmap' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"..
i have very little experience with coroutines so I'm not sure what to do.. please what is the right way to call this function .. thanks

sample code:
@Composable
private fun WallpaperCustomDialog() { Text(
             Modifier
              .clickable(onClick = {
               setHomeWallpaper(getBitmap() ) }